# Not able to use one-to-many relationship in sharkORM

Tags: ios, json, orm, model, key-value

I'm using [KeyValueObjectMapping](https://github.com/dchohfi/KeyValueObjectMapping) to convert JSON string to Model class.

Here is JSON string:

```
{
"id_str": "123456",
"name": "Some Name",
"protected": false,
"created_at": "Tue Mar 31 18:01:12 +0000 2009",
    "tweets" : [
        {
            "created_at" : "Sat Apr 14 00:20:07 +0000 2012",
            "id_str" : 190957570511478784,
            "text" : "Tweet text",
            "comments": {
                         "id_str":"2343",
                         "text":"This is comment1"
            }
        },
        {
            "created_at" : "Sat Apr 14 00:20:07 +0000 2012",
            "id_str" : 190957570511478784,
            "text" : "Tweet text",
            "comments": {
                         "id_str":"2343",
                         "text":"This is comment2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For which I have created model classes, like this:

For User,

```
@interface User : SRKObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *idStr;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) BOOL protected;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *createdAt;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tweets;

@end
```

For tweets,

```
@interface Tweet : SRKObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *idStr;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *createdAt;
@property(nonatomic, strong) Comments *comments;

@end
```

For Comments,

```
@interface Comments : SRKObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *idStr;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;

@end
```

It is working absolutely fine and I'm getting tweets in array. And I get tweets as user.tweets.

To save this in database, I'm using [SharkORM](https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm) for ORM. But while saving either it crash or don't save tweets at all.

Here is the issue open in repo (but using different example) - https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm/issues/78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Adrian_H for the efforts. I figured out the solution and posting here.

I have added below code in Tweet & Comments model to save tweets as NSArray and comments as model object and it worked.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the crash was the persistence of an array of Tweets stored in a User object as opposed to storing them as a separate class. See: [This](https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm/issues/78)

Ultimately what you want to end up with is ....

```
@interface Tweet : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) User* user;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *idStr;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *createdAt;

@end
```

As storing all tweets in an array object will just tie you in knots quickly (no searching, ever increasing save times).

So, when you get the JSON down, you can map the first class no problem, then iterate the tweets creating objects which are related to the User class.

Relating objects is just a case of setting the .user property with the relevant User entity which you have either created or queried for.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian_H for your answer and this make sense. But for the minimalistic changes, after adding "initWithCoder" and "encodeWithCoder" in the Tweet class its working fine and I am able to save/fetch tweets array. But now, its not saving comments object which is inside the tweet. Getting nil on [[tweets objectAtIndex:0] comments]. Any suggestions?

Comment: And you have also added the initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder to the Comments class?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. I'm getting status as unloaded - relationships =     (
                {
            property = "comments";
            status = unloaded;
            target = Comments;
        }

Comment: Yes you chose not to use any kind of relationships, so I would entirely expect that.  But as the object will be archived in one go,  if it's not working then there is some issue with your code in the initWithEncoder or encodeWithCoder

Comment: But there is relationship between Tweet & Comments as mentioned in my models. In Tweet model, I have added - @property(nonatomic, strong) Comments *comments; And its clearly says, it has relationship but status is unloaded -  relationships = ( { property = "comments"; status = unloaded; target = Comments; }

Comment: Hey @Adrian_H, thanks. Actually, I missed to add comments in my encoder code thats why it was not saving the comments data.